# C not reading values from input correctly

Tags: c, pointers, scanf, infinite-loop

I am very new to C, and while working on a project which requires pulling an indeterminate amount of values from the console, I am finding that it is not pulling the correct values. It seems like addresses, which I believe means it is a pointer issue, but I can't seem to find it.

```
int getVals(int degree){

        double sum;
        double x;
        double coefs[degree];
        for(int counter = 0; counter<=degree; counter = counter+1){
                double nxt;
                scanf(" %d", &nxt);
                coefs[counter] = nxt;
                printf("coefs[%d] = %d\n", counter, coefs[counter]);

        }
        printf(" x ? ");
        scanf(" %d", &x);
        printf("degree %d x %d\n", degree, x);
        sum = poly(x, degree, coefs);
                printf ("polynomial evaluate to: %lf\n", sum);
        int newDegree;
        scanf(" %d", &newDegree);
        degree = newDegree;
        if(degree>-1){
                getVals(degree);
        }
        else
                return degree;
}
```

Note: poly returns a double result of the evaluated polynomial
I am getting the following infinite loop after entering a degree of 1 and a coefficient of 1.5. It does not allow me to enter an x.
[Infinite loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lt3MU.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `scanf(" %d", &newDegree);` you should use the `"%lf"` format specifier (since your values is a `double`, not an `int`). Change the format specifier in all your calls to `scanf()` and `"%f"` in calls to `printf()`.

Please refer to the documentation at this links [*printf(3)*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html), [*scanf(3)*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html).

Comment: Also, you should probably show the code for the "poly" function.